# What happens if vendor partition is corrupted?

Tags: custom-roms, 8.0-oreo, lenovo

I  mistakenly flashed recovery image in vendor partition while installing a custom rom. I am using Lenovo K6 Power with Lineage OS Oreo Karate by Karthik with TWRP. I was flashing Resurrection Remix Oreo while this happened.

I haven't rebooted my device till now and it is charging. So what will happen now? When I try to flash RR I get error: `/vendor cannot be mounted`, when I try to restore I get the same error message.

Currently I am downloading stock rom and planning to flash it via Qfil in hopes of fixing it. Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/vendor` is sister partition of `/system` on Android devices which holds system applications and libraries that do not have source code available on AOSP but added by vendors (OEM's). It also contains SoC firmware images i.e. hardware specific libraries and binaries (OpenGL, ISP...).
Proprietary blobs (HALs) usually live in /vendor as shared libraries (.so files) which are loaded by Android binders when processes call a hardware component. This partition was optional before Treble support and `/vendor` used to be just a symlink to `/system/vendor`. However, on Treble devices it contains a separate filesystem, usually same as that of `/system` i.e. `ext4` or `f2fs`.

If you accidentally flashed recovery image over vendor partition, it won't brick your device unless you have a ROM or factory firmware to flash. However its filesystem is erased which needs to be recreated. Factory firmware flasher will do this for you but you can also manually format it from TWRP `Wipe` menu or through terminal emulator using `mkfs.ext4` or `mkfs.f2fs` commands.

Further reading: [ANDROID DEVICE PARTITIONS and FILESYSTEMS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565)